# react firebase hooks - cant use limit/where methods

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Im working with react hooks for firebase/firestore and React Native (expo). All working good to the moment when start using `limit` or `where` - operators. I'm getting an error that for ex. `limit is not a function` or just `undefined`. Same situation is for `where`

My code

```
import app from "../api/firebase";

...

const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(app), 'clients')
const queryRef = query(collectionRef).limit(5)

const [clients = [], loading, error] = useCollectionData(
  queryRef,
  {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  }
);
```

Error

```
TypeError: (0, _firestore2.query)(collectionRef).limit is not a function. (In '(0, _firestore2.query)(collectionRef).limit(5)', '(0, _firestore2.query)(collectionRef).limit' is undefined)
```

Deps:

```
 "@firebase/firestore": "^3.8.1",
 "expo": "~47.0.12",
 "expo-firebase-core": "~6.0.0",
 "firebase": "^9.16.0",
 "react": "18.1.0",
 "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
 "react-native": "0.70.5"
```

Comment: for firebase 9 import it from `firebase/firestore` and pass it as a second arg to query `query(collectionRef, limit(n))`

Comment: You are right. It's working. Thanks. Resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted answer with example query so if anyone facing the similar issue will find it easier as in the comments it is already resolved.

[react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore#usecollectiondata) is build using regular firebase SDK V9 so from [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) for query limiting you should use query in the following way:

```
const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(app), 'clients')
const queryRef = query(collectionRef, limit(5)); // ⇐

const [clients = [], loading, error] = useCollectionData(
  queryRef,
  {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  }
);
```